# Populate QCombobox with SQL Values

Tags: python, sql-server, pyqt, pyqt5, pyodbc

I'm trying to populate a `qcombobox` with values from an SQL table, but I get

> TypeError: addItems(self, Iterable[str]): argument 1 has unexpected type 'function'

My code is

```
self.building = QComboBox()
self.building.addItems(lambda: self.Buildingcombobox())
```

and

```
def Buildingcombobox(self):
    conn = pyodbc.connect(<connection>)
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT building, building_id FROM buildings")
    rows = cursor.fetchall()

    for row in rows:
        self.building.addItem(str(row[0]), row[1])
        print(row)
    
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
```

I'm selecting building and building_id because I want only building_id stored in the table employees.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `QComboBox()` object's `addItems()` method wants an *Iterable[Str]* parameter, not a function which adds items to the widget.

(For the SQL that you've quoted, you do not need to `commit` because you're not `INSERT`ing, `DELETE`ing or `UPDATE`ing).

I would remove the call to `addItems()` entirely, and use your `Buildcombobox` function (without the `commit`) because the `addItem()` call is doing what you need.